# Different proof for $W \le V \to \dim(W) \le \dim(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Larson Edwards Falvo - Elementary Linear Algebra

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Different approach:

Let $\dim(V) = n$. If $\dim(W) > n$, then a basis for $W$ has more than $n$ vectors, contradicting either of the theorems below. QED

Is that wrong? Am I doing some kind of catch-22 here?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Using theorem 4.10 will work very well. Theorem 4.11 doesn't really put you in a much better position than you started in. You have to know that you can extend a basis of $W$ to a basis of $V$. If you know that then you don't need the theorem anyway.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks! ^-^ Post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Theorem 4.10 will work very well. It shows that a basis of $W$ can't be bigger than a basis of $V$.

Theorem 4.11 doesn't really put you in a much better position than you started in. You have to know that you can extend a basis of $W$ to a basis of $V$. If you know that then you don't need the theorem anyway.

Comment: @bclc no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Both proofs are correct. 
They are actually using the same principle.
The proof above is using a direct method and the second one is using contradiction, the argument is exactly the same.

They are both implicitly using the fact that if $ w_1, w_2, \cdots w_n $ are elements of $W$ then necessarily $span(\{ w_1, w_2, \cdots, w_n \}) \subseteq V $